# glm Error: Define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE instead of GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE to use 0 to 1 clip space

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am using openGL and made the schoolboy error of not backing up my code and then breaking something. My code cannot compile as I have this error:

```
#error:  Define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE instead of GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE to use 0 to 1 clip space.
```

Since this error comes from the setup.hpp file of the glm library (below) and I also don't set GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE explicitly anywhere I think that somehow including the glm library is the problem but I can't figure out how to fix it again or how to find out why it has suddenly broken (other than asking here)

```
#ifdef GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE // Legacy 0.9.8 development
#   error Define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE instead of GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE to use 0 to 1 clip space.
#endif
```

I googled for this error but was surprised to find no results.

Thanks

Comment: How should we be able to tell you where you defined `GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE`?

Comment: That is why I have the question, that constant is not in any code that I have written. It can only be external code (I am assuming glm) that is changing the value but I don't know how to find the problem. That was what I meant when I said "I also don't set GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE explicitly anywhere" sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: That's because the error is about you set `GLM_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE` somewhere, so you searched for the wrong term.

Comment: just stumbled upon same error on a new PC.
Did you ever found a solution to this problem ?